# How can I use a route Paramter in a view model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

My Razor component starts like this:

```
@page "/track/{TrackId}"
@using BlazorSPA1.ViewModels
@inject ITrackViewModel TrackViewModel
```

My TrackViewModel has a public property TrackId:

```
[Parameter]
public string TrackId { get; set; }
```

The issue is that the TrackId property in my View vodel is ignored. I'll get the following exception:

> Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Object of type 'BlazorSPA1.Pages.Track' does not have a property matching the name 'TrackId'.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.ThrowForUnknownIncomingParameterName(Type targetType, String parameterName)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.SetProperties(ParameterView& parameters, Object target)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ParameterView.SetParameterProperties(Object target)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView parameters)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 newFrameIndex)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Int32 componentId, ArrayRange`1 oldTree, ArrayRange`1 newTree)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()

The only way to get rid of that excpetion is to define the property directly in my razor component:

```
@functions {
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            await base.OnInitializedAsync();
            await TrackViewModel.OnInitialyzeAsync();

        }

        [Parameter]
        public string TrackId { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to make this work using the property in my view model?

Comment: What is the baseclass of your ViewModel?  Blazor does [Parameter] injection on routable components so this not the way to do it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't have a baseclass yet.

Comment: so where does OnInitialyzeAsync come from?

Comment: From Blazor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#component-initialization-methods

Comment: So, again, what is the base class of (I)TrackViewModel?

Comment: Still no base class.

Comment: Post an outline of the class.